# Issues with customizing Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I have created stock graphs using amcharts library . I want a give a title and other things to this graph. Individual panel title are working. But Title for complete graph is not working.

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/hwhpguaf/

I tried to provide titles to graph but its not working

```
"titles": [
        {
            "text": "Chart Title",
            "size": 15
        }
    ]
```

Sample image of what I want[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock Chart does now have `titles` property and cannot have any additional titles and/or labels displayed on it.

You can however, add `titles` array to each individual panel, though:

```
panels: [{
    title: "Value",
    percentHeight: 70,

    "titles": [
        {
            "text": "Chart Title",
            "size": 15
        }
    ], ...
```

This will produce a title over the panel:

[image]

Here's updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hwhpguaf/1/

If however you are looking for a way to add a title over the whole of the chart, then putting as an external HTML element, might be an even straightforward solution:

```
<h2>Chart title</h2>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: yes , I have added that to panels and it shows in the middle of the graph and neither it have position attribute , so don't it look odd.  And about amchart titles but look here http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart . It have titles attribute

Comment: AmChart is a base class for the AmSerialChart which is turn is inherited by StockPanel. Therefore only panel has `titles` property, not the AmStockChart.

Comment: BTW, you could add `marginTop` in `panelsSettings` to make some space for the title.

Comment: Are that value axis labels, or something else?